# Xcode 8 Storyboard changes views frames automatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

In our project we are using xcode 8 combining autolayout and autoresizing. After having sometime, storyboard gets messed up. Subviews of Viewcontroller's view gets misplaced. How to get rid of this problem? Please help.

Comment: Are you setting constraints on all the views?

Comment: The view which is having resizing gets misplaced. Views with autolayout dont have any issues.

Comment: Use constraints on all the views I would suggest.

Comment: I'm not using autoresizing but sometimes notice the same problem. It's probably a bug of Xcode 8 itself. Not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you just update to any version of xcode8 from xcode7? There are many known issues with properly setting frames of view controllers once updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using constraints throughout the app works perfectly.